# Is a Generic Base Class Legal?

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

This seems to work, but I'm not 100% certain it's legal and would appreciate some feedback.

I have a subclass that is derived from a generic base class. It's similar to the curiously recurring template pattern, but different.

In derived.h:

```
template <class T>
class Derived : public T
{
public:
    Derived();
... and some other stuff ...
};
```

In derived.cpp:

```
#include "derived.h"

template <class T>
Derived<T>::Derived()
{
    ...
}

// defining the variations I need here avoids linker errors
// see http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/templates.html#faq-35.13
template Derived<Base1>::Derived();
template Derived<Base2>::Derived();
```

And in some other file:

```
#include "derived.h"

void test()
{
    Derived<Base1> d1;
    Derived<Base2> d2;
    ... do stuff with d1 and d2 ...
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can derive from any class, including one that is (or is dependent on) a template argument.

As noted in the comments, it must be a complete type; that is, it must have been defined before the template is instantiated.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I was worried after reading this: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/templates.html#faq-35.19 and 35.20. Just when I think I understand this stuff, I read something in the C++ faq that leaves me doubting myself.

Comment: @criddell: That's saying that you can't access base-class members in the usual way. Until the template is instantiated, there is no way to tell what the base-class members are, so you have to explicitly indicate that they are members, by using either `T::f()`, or `this->f()`.

Comment: Thanks Mike. Your explanation makes total sense.

Answer (score 5):

There's no such thing as a "generic class" in C++. What you have is a **template**, and a template is not a class. Rather, *instances* of the template *become* classes. However, those are entirely different, separate and unrelated classes, so `Derived<A>` and `Derived<B>` have nothing to do with one another.

Apart from that, what you're doing is perfectly fine. In any given template *instance* `Derived<T>`, `T` is an actual class (supposing it *is* actually a class, and not, say, an array or an `int`), and you can derive from it.

Comment: Yeah, "generic" is wrong but I was having a hard time figuring out how to word it. I thought about describing my Derived class as one with a templated base class, but then it sounds like the curiously recurring template pattern. Maybe "class derived from a template parameter"? That's awkward too.

Comment: @criddell: something like "Can a class template inherit from a template argument", or something in that direction. You should definitely get used to the word "template"!